# Does the current size of the cosmological sound horizon play a relevant role in the universe?

Tags: cosmology, acoustics, space-expansion, event-horizon

I am doing some interactive plots about cosmological horizons and in my research I stumbled upon the sound horizon, the baryonic acoustic oscillations and how it had an impact on the formation of the first structures in the universe.

Some people have calculated the radius of the sound horizon at the time of recombination using the same equation used in the particle horizon but with the speed of "sound", which itself is a function of the density of matter and radiation. But I've never seen anyone actually plot the radius into the future like some have done with other cosmological horizons. Is there a reason for that? Does it not play an important role in the universe anymore? Was it only important at the time of recombination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### The sound horizon is the same today as at recombination.

Before the time of [recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recombination_(cosmology)), the universe was full of free protons and electrons. Due to the electric charges of these particles, collisions were frequent. Via these collisions, sound waves were able to propagate. The idea of a sound wave is that a region of excess density exerts pressure on surrounding regions, squeezing them and making them exert pressure on their surroundings in turn. But this connection between density and pressure requires frequent particle collisions.

During recombination, the free protons and electrons combined to make atoms. Collisions essentially stopped, since the atoms are electrically neutral. So the sound waves froze in place. Technically, they froze in [comoving coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comoving_and_proper_distances#Comoving_coordinates); the structure left by the sound waves continued to expand, following the expansion of the universe, but the sound waves stopped propagating.

This is observationally confirmed since 2005, when [astronomers detected these sound waves in the spatial distribution of galaxies](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0501171). The sound horizon is, in comoving units, the same in the galaxy distribution as in the cosmic microwave background.